# Pointer as index of one array - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having trouble to make the following algorithm work without index (with index it works). It's a small exercise for my university, and one of the requirements is that I can only use "pointer reference" to walk through my allocated array (frase), not index. What I've tried last to make it work is commented, and I give up because anything I try doesn't work... Thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char* frase;
    frase = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    gets(frase);

    /*
    while(*frase != '\0'){
        printf("%c", *frase);
        frase++;
    }
    */
    int i = 0;
    while(frase[i]){
        printf("%c", toupper(frase[i]));
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    free(frase);
}
```

Comment: What didn't work? The commented code seems OK. Except to the fact that you won't be able to `free` it afterwars, as you loose the original pointer. So you'll have to save it before incrementing.

Comment: do `while(*(frase + i))` and `toupper(*(frase + i))`. Change those to the ones I have written and try again :)

Comment: Eugene, with the commented code i was getting lot of crashs and my pc restarting, probably due to bad memory manage or something...

Comment: i ill try d3r1ck and give the feedback, thanks

Comment: Have you read the part about `free`?

Comment: Yeah, now i understand what i did wrong and how bad memory management can be a trouble. I tried MD XF and Paul Ogilvie code's together and it work. Also d3r1ck code worked too. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you free a pointer which has changed (indeed, `frase` has been incremented using `frase++`)
then `free(frase)` does not work.

Comment: I agree that free is a problem, but my main problem was my while being a infinite loop until my pc crash... Anyway its solved now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By using "pointers only" you point to an element, process it and then increment the pointer to point to the next element:

```
char *pfrase = frase;
while(pfrase){
    printf("%c", toupper(pfrase));
    pfrase++;
}
```

Comment: I used ur code within MD XF logic:  while(*pfrase) , toupper(*pfrase) and *pfrase++, and its working well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The value of the argument passed to `free` must be a pointer that was returned by one of the `malloc` family of functions. If a different value is passed to `free`, the program has undefined behavior.

When you use:

```
frase = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

gets(frase);

while(*frase != '\0'){
   printf("%c", *frase);
   frase++;
}

free(frase);
```

You are calling `free` using a pointer whose value is different than the value returned by `malloc`. That is cause for undefined behavior.

One way to resolve this is what you have already done -- use an index to access the array.

Another way to resolve this is to use a different variable to iterate over the contents of the array.

```
frase = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

gets(frase);

// Don't modify frase. Use another variable to iterate
char* cp = frase;
while(*cp != '\0'){
   printf("%c", *cp);
   cp++;
}

free(frase);
```

Answer (score -1):

With everyone responses, my algorithm is working now. Here is what its now:

```
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <ctype.h>

      int main(){

           char* frase;
           frase = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

           gets(frase);

           char* pointer = frase;
           while(*pointer){
                printf("%c", toupper(*pointer));
                *pointer++;
                }


           printf("\n");
           free(frase);
           free(pointer);
           }
```

Both the problem of dont edit my "frase" array and the useless free problem seems to be solved. Also, i know about the gets problem, but this algorithm is for a exercise. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Ai!!! You can't free `pointer` because it was pointing to `frase`, and you `freed` `frase` already! - Remove the `free(pointer);`

Comment: hmmm, now i see it. Thanks!